# How to get ckeditor to work in Django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor

I'm trying to get a blog up but I need ckeditor in Django admin to make posts.

In this link https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor it gives the instructions for getting ckeditor on Django admin and I don't understand step 3 which says this:

> django-ckeditor uses jQuery in ckeditor-init.js file. You must set
>   `CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL` to a jQuery URL that will be used to load the
>   library. If you have jQuery loaded from a different source just don't
>   set [CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL] and django-ckeditor will not try to load its
>   own jQuery. If you find that CKEditor widgets don't appear in your
>   Django admin site, then check that this variable is set correctly.
>   Example:
>
> CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL =
>   'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'

Can somebody go into better detail of how to execute this step?  What do I copy, paste, edit or configure in what file?

I went on a limb and pasted the above URL in settings.py and moved on to step 4 which failed too.

There aren't much other resources for how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy this

```
CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'
```

to settings.py